# SQL 'WHERE' restriction based on SUM

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I am computing current positions by summing historical transactions, using

```
SELECT pairID, instrumentID, Sum(sharesTraded)
FROM cef_schema.pairadj_table 
GROUP BY pairID, instrumentID ORDER BY pairID;
```

This works fine, but produces responses for every pair even if the current position (sum of sharesTraded) is 0. I would prefer to omit these, but get an error if I try to restrict the SELECT with `WHERE Sum(sharesTraded)!=0`.

Is there some way to restrict the results to non-zero sums?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT pairID, instrumentID, Sum(sharesTraded) as sharesTradedSum
FROM cef_schema.pairadj_table 
GROUP BY pairID, instrumentID 
HAVING sharesTradedSum > 0
ORDER BY pairID
```

Comment: This seems incompatible with GROUP BY in MySQL (I'm getting an error code 1064); my goal is to compute the total for each instrument in each pair, not the total for everything put together.

Comment: No it isn't. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html @MichaelStern What does the error message say?

Comment: Ah, it was puking because I had ORDER BY before HAVING. It needs to come after. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Need to use `HAVING` with `GROUP BY` instead of `WHERE`.